# numpy create a boolean array of False

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I try to initialize a `Boolean` array with `False` using `np.empty`,

```
init_arr = empty(5)
init_arr.fill(False)
```

but I got

```
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

then I create a `pd.Series`,

```
dummy_ser = pd.Series(data=init_arr)
```

which makes it

```
0       0
1       0
2       0
3       0
4       0
```

I tried to initialize a boolean series with various length with `False` as its initialized values. I am wondering whats the best way to do this.

I am using `Python 3.5.2` and `Numpy 1.15.4`.

Comment: Use `np.zeros(5, dtype=bool)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `empty()` function creates an array of floats:

```
In [14]: np.empty(5).dtype
Out[14]: dtype('float64')
```

There are many ways to solve this, supplying `dtype=bool` to `empty()` being one of them.

But I would create an array of `False` like this:

```
In [17]: np.full(5, False)
Out[17]: array([False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do :

```py
np.zeros(5).astype(bool)
```

Comment: This will needlessly create an `int` array first, and cast it to `bool` later, wasting space in the meantime.

Comment: yeah I agree, I think the efficient way to do so is doing `np.zeros(5, dtype = bool)` as @jdehesa suggested

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.broadcast_to(False, (2, 2))
array([[ False,  False],
   [ False,  False]], dtype=bool)
```